# Puzzle involving - and \

Tags: puzzle-creation

This is a good fun puzzle I made up for my students. Thought people here would enjoy it.

[image]

Comment: the puzzle-creation tag is for asking about creating puzzles. If you just want to pose us a puzzle, use some tags that describe it. Also, do you have the original you printed that from? The picture is very hard to work with.

Comment: Perhaps / also should be added in the title.

Comment: Matt. A better picture would go a long way too. For example cant tell if the very first signs at the top left are slashes or not

Comment: That [black](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55977/been-stuck-on-this-for-a-long-time) [background](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/cryptic-symbols-and-letters) looks familiar.

Answer (score 1):

> This is semaphore. Using the flags you get the sentence asking what is the fifth Mersenne prime. A quick Google will tell you that the answer is therefore 8191 :)